# Configure EasyPHP to use CGI

Tags: cgi, config, easyphp

I'm trying to modify my EasyPHP to run in CGI mode.

According to this link: http://www.easyvitools.com/phpserial/php_ser_reference.html
I have to add in this line:
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files/EasyPHP 2.0b1/php5/php5apache2.dll" to httpd.conf

However, everytime I do that, EasyPHP gives me this error:

> Error in Apache configuration file:
>
> ""apache.exe: syntax error on line 126
>   of ..../apache/conf/httpd.conf. API
>   module structure 'php5_module' in the
>   file C:..../php5/php5apache2.dll is
>   garbled - perhaps this is not an
>   APache module DSO?""

I've checked that the file php5apache2.dll exists and that it is correct in the config file.  Does anybody know what could cause this problem or am I doing something wrong to change it to CGI mode instead of using the default APache handler?

Answer (score 5):

I believe that you may need to re-read the instructions:

**Comment** this line:

```
#LoadModule php5_module "c:/Php/php5apache2.dll"
```

And add 2 new lines:

ScriptAlias /php/ "c:/php/"
Action application/x-httpd-php "/php/php-cgi.exe"

So it appears that the line you are adding actually needs to be commented out / removed. And you need to use these alternative directives in httpd.conf.